# MongoDB, Mongoose and Node.js update stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a big collection in MongoDB: size - `94.605.081.327 B` count - `54.738.234`. I have to change all documents in this collection, and it can't be done in a single `update`.

I would like to stream the data and update the collection one document at a time. Another developer on the same project recommended an approach like this:

```
stream.on('data', (data)=>{
    stream.pause();
    data.field = 'newValue'; // update
    data.save((err)=>{
        stream.resume();
    })
})
```

Is it a good idea? Is there a more efficient way of doing this `update`  with `Node.js` and `Mongoose`?

Comment: You could read the data in batches, update every entry in a batch, and write the batch back. MongoDB offers `skip`and `limit` to load only a section of a result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`bulk operation`**. Check out [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) for detailed information. If you need to involve `mongoose`, your code would look something like this:

```js
var bulk = Items.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find(query).update(update);
bulk.execute(function(error) {
     callback();                   
});
```